# Dark mode overwriting colors in email

Tags: html, email, html-email

Most of the issues have been cleared up but one of my `h1`'s will turn black in dark mode on Outlook 360 and I'm not quite sure as to why.

```
<h1 mc:edit="header-title"
   color="#ffffff"
   mc:label="header-title"
   class="header-title darkmodecolor"
   style="margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;color: white !important;font-weight: 700;font-size: 28px;line-height: 140% !important;">
   <span
      class="header-title darkmodecolor"
      style="color: white !important;">
        text is here
   </span>
</h1>
```

I have tried using the color scheme media query but nothing is affecting it.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: https://ibb.co/nQrkF2J

Comment: It occurs when the text is inside of a background color

Comment: And what's your CSS?

Comment: ALso, are you just testing Outlook 365? Did you realise there's a whole bunch of different behaviours - and some will never respect your wishes? In which case, you might want to rethink what you are doing. See https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/

Comment: Yeah, It works okay on the rest of them its just this one giving me trouble. I have used all solutions i could find and none have worked for this particular one so i will have to accept that it doesn't want to listen to me